# Printing the results of button clicking Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have 5 fieldsets that after clicking through the buttons I want to show that the results went through. As you can see I just want to click the buttons then move on and at the end have a list of what was chosen.

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
            var results = "";
            $('button').click(function() {
            results += $(this).attr("value") + "<br>";
            });
            $("#demo").html(results);
       });
```

Here is the html code

```
     <fieldset>
      <h2 class="fs-title">Pick a Type</h2>


    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="VoIP"  /> <br>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Analog" />

    </br>
    <input type="text" name="custom" placeholder="Custom" style="width: 100px;"/>
    <br>

    <!--<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" style="float:right" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" style="float:left" />
    -->
      </fieldset>
     <fieldset>

     <h2 class="fs-title">Pick a Sub-Type</h2>


    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Desk Phone"  /><br>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Polycom" /> <br>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Wireless Phone" style="white-space:normal"/> <br>
    <input type="text" name="customsub" placeholder="Custom " style="width: 100px;"/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    </br>
    <!--<input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Cancel" style="float:left" /> -->

</fieldset>
<fieldset>

    <h2 class="fs-title">Enter Model</h2>
    <input type="text" name="model" placeholder="Model"/>
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" style="float:right" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" style="float:left" />

</fieldset>
<fieldset id="sample">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Complete</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Equipment Added Successfully!</h3>
    <p id="demo"> </p>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Add Another" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Done" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Can you give HTML too please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that code, you're going to set the HTML of the `#demo` element *immediately*.

What you want to do is add things as buttons are clicked. Usually using `<br>` to separate things isn't ideal; instead, append `div` or `p` elements or similar:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $("#demo").append("<div>" + this.value + "</div>");
    });
});
```

Note that that assumes the `button` elements have `value` attributes (as that's what you were using in your example). If not, use `$(this).text()` or `$(this).html()` instead of `this.value`.

Full example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/yacoji/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button value="1">One</button>
  <button value="2">Two</button>
  <button value="3">Three</button>
  <button value="4">Four</button>
  <div id="demo"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $("#demo").append("<div>" + this.value + "</div>");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```